# Need help in matching regexp

Tags: regex, perl

I am having a string say

```
my $str = "FILLER-1-1,EQPT:MN,EQPT_MISSING,NSA,04-30,15-07-13,NEND,NA";
```

I want to match a pattern say

```
my $pattern = "FILLER-1-1";
```

I am using the below regexp

```
$reg = $str =~ /$pattern/;
```

This is working fine

Now the problem is it is also matching if our string is

```
FILLER-1-10/FILLER-1-11/FILLER-1-12 so on ...
```

I dont want to match this. Also I don't want my regexp to be like

```
 $reg = $str =~ /$pattern\W+/;
```

This one is working against the above mentioned issue but `\W` may come or not come. In some strings it can come while in other it may not come. So i need the regexp to match only `FILLER-1-1` without using `\W+` and it should match specifically `FILLER-1-10`

Note: If somebody is doing `-`(minus) rating to my question, please let me know what's wrong in the code. It will be appreciable if the person write the comment too

Comment: Do you want to match `FILLER-number-number`?

Comment: Do you want to match FILLER-1-1 and not FILLER-1-10? And FILLER-1-1 may appear at the end if the line?

Comment: @Bohemian: Yes it may come at end of line or inbetween line or anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As \w matches [a-zA-Z0-9], you can use the zero-width assumption \b, which denotes a change in \w state (called a "word boundary", hence the "b" shortcut):

/FILLER-1-1\b/

This means that there needs to be a character that differs from the previous word state - a word state change.

It will match

```
FILLER-1-1.
FILLER-1-1&
FILLER-1-1,
```

It will not match

```
FILLER-1-1a
FILLER-1-16
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

Comment: \b is space not change in \w state.

Comment: @Nitesh Follow the link I posted, and you find: "The metacharacter \b is an anchor like the caret and the dollar sign. It matches at a position that is called a "word boundary". This match is zero-length."

Comment: yes it is a word boundary. But it needs space after that . Say /FILLER-1-1\b/. It means it is looking for space after the string

Comment: It seems you didn't understand the referenced explanation article for \b. It doesn't look for a space, it looks for a non-word (aka \w) character if there is one to the left of the \b. Everything [^a-zA-Z0-9] will match there. That can also be a space.

Comment: Sorry. I got this now. Sorry for previous comment. It is working now. Thanks a lot

Comment: Please edit you answer a bit so that i can give +1 to the answer

Comment: \b does NOT require a space. It requires a non-word char or end of line. I think this is a good answer +1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match `FILLER` at the start of the input (line) followed by two numbers, this simple regex should work:

```
/~FILLER-\d+-\d+/
```

- `~` matches the beginning of the input
- `\d` matches any digit (`[0-9]`)
- `+` matches at least one, but can match any number

Comment: It will not serve the purpose.

Comment: @Nitesh: Why not? Can you change an input that matches but should not?

Answer (score -1):

use `?` quantifier like so:

```
/FILLER-\d-\d\W?/
```

The `\W?` means not a word zero or one time

Comment: `\W` means not a word _character_ (most of the time that means `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`).

Comment: my dear friend `\W?` will not serve the purpose. It will also match `FILLER-1-12` too that is not required